# Decision Tree classifier throws KeyError: 'log_loss'

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I used Decision Tree from sklearn, normally there is log_loss

```
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 42,class_weight ='balanced' ,criterion='log_loss')
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

error :

```
KeyError: 'log_loss'
```

Answer (score 4):

The `log_loss` option for the parameter `criterion` was added only in the latest scikit-learn [version 1.1.2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier):

> ***criterion{“gini”, “entropy”, “log_loss”}, default=”gini”***

It is not  there in either of the two previous ones, [version 1.0.2](https://scikit-learn.org/1.0/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier_) or [version 0.24.2](https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier):

> ***criterion{“gini”, “entropy”}, default=”gini”***

The error suggests that you are using an older version; you can check your scikit-learn version with

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

So, you will need to upgrade scikit-learn to v1.1.2.